# debug HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets

I am trying to create my own eshop. I have some problems. I think that the problem is on xml files so I do not post my classes, controllers etc. If you ask me to post, I will.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <beans profile="dev">

        <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore.dao, com.emusicstore.impl"></context:component-scan> 


        <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">

            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
        </bean>

        <!-- MY CHANGES -->
        <!-- LocalSessionFactoryBean for hibernate4 -->

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <!-- CHANGE HERE FOR MySQL -->
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <!-- To know where is ProductDao -->
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.emusicstore.dao</value>
                    <value>com.emusicstore.impl</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </beans>
</beans>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore." />

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

**web.xml** (part of my code)

```
        <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param> 
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The first error is the following

```
        HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

    type Exception report

    message Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Then all the following errors are:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanCreationDefinitionException
```

I appreciate any kind of help. 
Thank in advance, Mike

**EDIT**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dao.ProductDao controllers.HomeController.productDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.ProductDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**ProductDao**

```
package com.emusicstore.dao;
import java.util.List;
import com.emusicstore.model.Product;
public interface ProductDao 
{
    void addProduct(Product product);
    Product getProductById (String id);
    List<Product> getAllProducts();
    void deleteProduct (String id);
}
```

**ProductDaoImpl**

```
package com.emusicstore.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.emusicstore.dao.ProductDao;
import com.emusicstore.model.Product;

@Component
@Transactional
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addProduct(Product product) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(product);
    session.flush();
}

public Product getProductById(String id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class, id);
    session.flush();

    return product;
}

public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Product");
    List<Product> products = query.list();
    session.flush();

    return products;
}

public void deleteProduct(String id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.delete(getProductById(id));
    session.flush();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post full error log?

Comment: I have just updated my post.

Comment: what about ProductDao?

Comment: At ProductDao I define my methods. At ProduDaoImpl implements Product I write the code for all the methods and I use an @Autowired SessionFactory.

Comment: Error says - it is not able to create bean for productDao, Can you post that class?

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy once again look at my updated post..

Answer (score 0):

You can **tell Spring** to use your ProductDaoImpl bean by using `@Qualifier` annotation as below.

```
@Autowire
@Qualifier("productDaoImpl") 
ProductDao productDao;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same error appears. :( I am going to check my pom.xml to see if I am using the right dependencies.